# setting a variable with <g:set> from drop down list in Grails

Tags: grails

in Grails gsp , 
i what to assign a variable when the user makes a choice from drop down list , in another way when user chooses the value from :

```
<g:select name="patient.id" from="${patients}" optionKey="id" >
```

i want to set the patient's id to "pid" variable in the below :

```
<g:set var="pid" scope="request">
```

the only way that succeeded with me is :

```
<g:set var="pid" value="${2}" scope="request">
```

but this is not dynamic way .

how can i achieve that ?

thanks
Sherif

Comment: GSP is server side code, executed before HTML sent to a browser. you cannot use a variable after. what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

`g:set` is actually not an html field and you are trying to assign an java object from html/js code.

You can't assign any Java Object a js variable from client side scripting.If you need a workaround to achieve this only then the max you can do is:

```
$('#your_select').on('change',function(){
if($('this').val()=="bingo"){
var X="${pid="bingo"}" //if will assign pid a string "bingo" and X(a js var) value "bingo"
}
}
```

See the code between `${}` is server side code and you can't write any client side code into it so basically you can't just do something like `"${pid=$(this).val()}"`.

If you wonder why we can't do this is because there  is no need to do this and it does not make sense too as described in **Igor Artamonov**'s comment.

Comment: any reply for my question ?

Comment: @SShehab if you explain what you want to do after  assigning 'pid' may be we can help more because this is a really bad thing to do. You should play with client side variables if you want changes on client side only.

Comment: ok the case is like this when the user chooses a patient from the dropdown list i have to know this patient;s ID and got to the DB and fetch the prescriptions related to him , so like i said before i need the patient's ID for the selection to be able to fetch the prescriptions this is why i want to put it in a variable , if you got another way to achieve this scenario i'll be grateful

Answer (score 0):

In you don't need some workaround as i described in my another answer then the optimum solution for sort of requirements is:

1. Get the value of select in some js variable.
2. Make an AJAX call to server action that will send data according to request parameters so in this case one parameter will your selected value.
3. Receive the AJAX response and set the html elements based on response.

So the example would be:

```
var selected = $('#your_select_id).val();
jQuery.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'your action url that will render response',
                    data: "selected="+selected,
                    async: false,
                    success: function(response,textStatus){
                        json= JSON.parse(response);
                        $('#some_textBox).val(json.somevalue);
                     },
                    error:function(XMLHttpRequest,textStatus,errorThrown){}
                });
```

Comment: @SShehab if you can not understand  this then you might need to first understand basics of web development.